# Django ManyToManyField to self drops error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to register ManyToManyField to self object and I am getting error when I am trying to access page with listings for Client model

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

This is how my models looks like:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('self',symmetrical=False,blank=True,through='Friends')

class Friends(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Client,related_name='contact')
```

I have also tried to remove through part, so it was like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        contacts = models.ManyToManyField('self',symmetrical=False,blank=True)
```

I am not quite sure what am I doing wrong. I am just trying to register Client that can have multiple clients(contacts) attached on it. Can you advice what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Updated - traceback:

```
AttributeError at /client/
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py in get_url, line 202
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/bobandavidovic/PycharmProjects/myapp/myapp',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 7 Jun 2015 00:00:39 +0200
```

Update - I am using Django Rest Framework

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: Your traceback indicates that you are using DRF, which you should have mentioned. The problem is almost certainly in your serializer, not your models.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you were right! Thanks! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. The problem was in the serializer, since I haven't serialize contacts properly.

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you try adding a related_name argument to your ManyToMany field. eg:

```
contacts = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='client', symmetrical=False, blank=True, through='Friends')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried it and error is still the same.

Comment: yeah, I didn't catch what Daniel did from your traceback.

Comment: Thanks for proposed solution. Daniel was right, so problem wasn't in models, problem was in serializer - contacts weren't serialized properly.